# linear algebra problem - how to solve

Tags: linear-algebra

Over $i^2$  there is $U=${$(x,y)|y=1/5x$}.

Let $v=(52,52)$ vector.

Let $p\in U^\perp$ such that $v-p\in U$
so what is the value of $||p||$?

I know the answer is $8 \sqrt{26}$ but I can't see how to get it...

(hope everything is clear since im not english speaker)

Comment: I don't understand the notation in the first line

Comment: which part exactly??

Comment: $i^2U$ [spacefiller]

Comment: edited... and now?

Comment: Do you mean "let $p\in U^\perp$"?

Comment: Let me try: $U$ is the line with $y=\frac{x}{5}$ and $v=(52,52)$. If $p$ is the perpendicular component of $v$, what is $\Vert p \Vert$?

Comment: @GitGud Yes thank you!

Comment: Do you mean $v-p\in U$?

Comment: @GitGud Yes I did

Comment: I still don't understand what "over $i^2$" means. I don't know if this is allowed, but can you reply with a comment in your own language stating that part?

Comment: over complex numbers... I think i^2 is same as in the question

Comment: Hum, really? Over $\mathbb{C}$? This screams $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: yes maybe it's mistake in the question? im not sure
but if there is any way to get to this solution ill be happy if someone will show me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsure of what's being asked I suggest the following:

Notice that $U=\{(x,\frac{1}{5}x) | x\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Now what's $U^\perp$? Check that it is $U^\perp=\{(-x,5x) | x\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Now take $p\in U^\perp$ such that $v-p\in U$. Because $p\in U^\perp$ you know that $p=(-5\alpha, \alpha)$, for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. So we get $v-p=(52+5\alpha, 52 -\alpha) $. But now we want $v-p\in U$.

Because $\{(5x,x) | x\in \mathbb{R}\}=\{(x,\frac{1}{5}x) | x\in \mathbb{R}\} = U$, we know that $v-p\in U$ if, and only if, $5\cdot(52+5\alpha)=52-\alpha$.

Solving for $\alpha$ in order to get $v-p\in U$, follows that $\alpha=-8$.

Therefore $p=(40,-8)$ and $||p||=\sqrt {40^2+8^2}=\sqrt{8^2\cdot5^2+8^2}=\sqrt{8^2\cdot(25+1)}=\sqrt{8^2}\sqrt{26}=8\sqrt{26}$.

Comment: thank you for your  answer
actually this is exactly where I was stuck
(52,52)-(-5x,x)=?

Comment: I wrote the solution farther, but I didn't finish it. I must go to bed now. Good luck.

Comment: how can I make it ∈U? this is  where I was stuck from beginning

Comment: I solved it on the answer.